# Why can't an answer marked as community wiki be changed back to a normal post?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Why can't a decision to make an answer `community wiki` be reversed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: CW can now be reversed by a moderator.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's about gaming.  A community wiki post is one that belongs to the *community*.  It doesn't matter if it got that way by the number of edits, or by the OP "donating" it to the community by checking the box manually, it's still community owned.  It would seem rude to me for an individual to take back something that was owned by the community.

I can still see the need for it if the box was checked accidentally.  In this case I think it should be possible to uncheck the box within the initial 5-minute edit "grace period".

Comment: With the ability to tick it back (without rollback this time) on a posterior edit.

Comment: Does taking it back during that grace period also give back answers that were forced to community wiki in the interim?

Comment: @Jeff: Just to clarify, this isn't how it currently works, I'm just suggesting that this is how it *could* work.  To answer your question, yes I think that would only be fair.

Comment: What about people who answered with a CW answer on purpose?

Comment: @Brad: What about them?  If they answered CW on purpose then I don't see how they're affected.

Comment: @Bill, I like your answer, but you may want to modify the FAQ: "There is no way to reclaim your post back from Community Wiki mode. This is to prevent exploits and gaming of the system."

Answer (score 4):

My guess,

To prevent gaming. I do think there are some exceptional cases where it is fair for a question or answer to go back to normal mode. Perhaps the moderators need that power.

Comment: +1 for giving the mods that power.