# How should modifications to official FAQ questions be handled?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, meta-faq

I was just thinking that the [official FAQ on Community Wiki questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) should explain how and why the "author info" space of CW questions — e.g. "community wiki / 
14 revs, 13 users..." —  differs from the same space on a regular questions — e.g. "asked Jan 11 at 17:05 / Popular Demand / 700 ●1●13 / 93% accept rate."  In particular, I've seen confusion in the past about whether the name given is the OP or the most recent editor.

But, since it takes a mod to bestow the official red `faq` tag, I didn't want to modify the question directly.  I also didn't want to ask it as a separate question, because it would just have to be merged with the FAQ afterwards, which is messy at best.  So, what's the proper procedure for dealing with FAQ edits/situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're unsure about how to make an official FAQ question edit or what to put in it, I don't see a problem with asking a new question to clarify.

Once consensus is reached on what to add to the official FAQ question, the new question can be closed as a dupe of the FAQ. Yeah, it's a little messier that way, but if the issue is nontrivial or it's omitted and you're not sure what to write, then there should be a discussion about it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that [[faq-update-request]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-update-request) exists for this.

Comment: Though several of those are talking about http://stackoverflow.com/faq instead of [[faq]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: Yeah, it's a double-duty tag alright... don't see a way around it until one or both of the things currently called "faq" are renamed, though.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Retag it with `faq-proposed` then when you are satisfied with your update flag it for mod attention so they can retag it with `faq`.</strike>

Turns out the `faq` tag cannot be added or removed by a normal user, but once it's there the question can still be edited, and the tag left in there.

However, you may still need to add one of the other required tags (`discussion`, usually).

You can see this on an edit I made to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3866/why-an-answer-marked-as-community-wiki-cannot-be-changed-back-to-a-normal-post) (probably tagged faq long before the "official" tags became restricted).

At any rate, if you feel additional discussion should occur prior to editing the official `faq` tagged question, follow Jon's advice and start a new question.  Otherwise, go ahead and edit the `faq` tagged questions directly - they'll go to the front page and others will check them out for you, and edit if they disagree.

Comment: Normally, that's what I would do.  But in this case the question really should be part of the larger FAQ post on CW questions, not a separate FAQ question of its own.

Comment: @Popular - No, I mean edit the question itself - don't start a new question.  Edit the existing question, remove the `faq` tag, put in the `faq-proposed` tag, and flag it for mod attention so they can put the `faq` tag back on the question.

Comment: Oh, okay, yes, I misunderstood.  But that's kinda sketchy too.  First of all, if only mods can add the `faq` tag, it seems unreasonable that any old user can strip it off.  Second, it would quasi-eliminate the faq entry about CW for the duration of the edit, and relies on mods to notice that entry in their queue quickly.

Comment: I don't believe the mod-only tags can be *removed* by regular users.

Comment: @Jon - I learn a new thing every day.  Thanks, I updated my answer.